# Can I set the local timezone in my browser via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I know I can get the local timezone offset via new Date().getTimeZoneOffset().  But where did Javascript get that information?  Is there a way I can set it, so that all future Date objects have the offset I want?  I tried searching the DOM in Firebug, but couldn't find anything.

What I am trying to accomplish is converting epoch times to readable format, but it needs to be in US/Central, no matter what the browser's OS setting.  Because I am using US/Central, it's not a fixed difference from GMT.  So instead of a bunch of super nasty conversion steps, why can't I just tell Javascript that I'm actually in US/Central?

Comment: There may be several "nasty conversion steps" involved, but can't you encapsulate those steps in your own `GetUSCentralDate()` function and then just use that whenever you need a new Date object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know I can get the local timezone offset via new Date().getTimeZoneOffset(). But where did Javascript get that information?

[An implementation of ECMAScript is expected to determine the local time zone adjustment.](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.7)

> Is there a way I can set it, so that all future Date objects have the offset I want?

No.

> So instead of a bunch of super nasty conversion steps, why can't I just tell Javascript that I'm actually in US/Central?

Have you considered using [a library](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)?

Comment: That TimezoneJS.Date library depends on the Olson timezone database files, which are no longer available.  No other Javascript date library seems to have this kind of functionality.

Comment: A better and more actual library nowadays, for the OP use-case (and that of many others) is using moment-timezone, as explained in another answer here.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, Moment-Timezone enables us to set the "browser's" default timezone by using [`moment.tz.setDefault()`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/).

You'll have to use `moment()` instead of `Date()`, but this is still a nice upgrade over the weird JS Date object.

Comment: You should consider using other libs instead, `moment.js` recommends this as well (it is in the docs)

Answer (score 0):

### Output format

If you are concerned about the output format, you always need to format you `Date` object prior to outputting it if you need it in a local timezone (e.g. using [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)) or you a library like [`dayjs`](https://day.js.org/) or [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/).

### Create a new `Date` object from a date with a non-UTC timezone

You can set an offset in pure JS: `new Date('2022-10-29T12:50:00.000+02:00')` will contain `2022-10-29T10:50:00.000Z`. You just have to always specify the timezone offset in `/^[+-][0-2]\d:[0-5]\d$/` format.

```js
console.log(new Date('2022-10-29T12:50:00.000+02:00').toISOString())
// Output
// 2022-10-29T10:50:00.000Z
```

#### Get timezone offset string from timezone offset number

Now, if you want to get an offset in that format from `(new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()` (e.g. `-120`), you need to

```js
const tzOffsetNumber = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()
const tzOffsetString = `${tzOffsetNumber > 0 ? '+' : '-'}${Math.floor(Math.abs(tzOffsetNumber) / 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${(Math.abs(tzOffsetNumber) % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')}`
```

#### Get timezone offset string from IANA timezone

```js
// Note: We need to specify a date in order to also consider DST settings.
const date = new Date()
const ianaTimezone = 'Europe/Bratislava'
const tzOffsetString = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {timeZone: ianaTimezone, timeZoneName: 'longOffset'}).format(date).match(/[\d+:-]+$/)?.[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old post, but [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is a powerful javascript library to manipulate date/time objects

Comment: You should consider using other libs instead, `moment.js` recommends this as well (it is in the docs)